# Find all word ocurrencies inside a textarea with jquery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, match, cpu-word

### I need some help to achieve this. I have a textarea and a "search form" where i put a word to find in a textarea and count how many matches are found.

Actual working code

```
$("#encontrar").click(function(){
    var palabra = $("#palabra").val();
    var codigo = $("#codigo").val();
    var str = codigo, strToMatch = palabra,
    re = new RegExp(palabra,'ig');
    var numero = str.match(re).length;
    alert(numero);
})
```

Comment: you can achieve it by using .match().length with a regex

Comment: and please show what you have done so far.

Comment: why to downvote this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regular expression

```
var str = "Hey hello hi history hey", strToMatch = 'hey',
 re = new RegExp('hey','ig');
 str.match(re).length;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Vaibhav for your help, after playing a litle with your suggestion it works as expected!